# No scroll bar for Bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason Bootstrap isn't showing any scroll bar when the modal gets too long.

The problem here is that we can't scroll down to click on the "Save Changes" button as shown in the left picture.

To get to the save button, we have to zoom out (as shown in the right picture). A scroll bar would be nice here.

```
    <div id="myModal-client" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-        labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="form-client-details" method="post" action="ajax/update_client_info.php" style="margin:0;">
              <div class="modal-header">
                 <h3 id="myModalLabel">
                   Update Client Details
                 </h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="messages"></div>
                  <table id="client-details-table" class="table">
                   <!-- all the basic table tr and td stuff here -->
                  </table>
                 <input type='hidden' name='campaign_id' value='<?php echo $campaignId; ?>'>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btncancel" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style='padding-right: 10px;'>
                cancel
              </a>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success" id="saveClientInfo" value="Save changes" data-loading-text="loading...">
           </div>
         </form>
       </div>
     </div>
```

[image: On the left is what the users will see at 100% default view. On the right is what users will see when they zoom out.]

Bootstrap version: 3.2.0

Comment: Will you please offer a jsfiddle. I have run a demo using your html code, but it seems to work fine. Here's the demo http://jsfiddle.net/1tudc11o/

Comment: Works fine: http://jsbin.com/yefas/1

Comment: Presumably you've added other CSS to your page that's interfering with Bootstrap.

Comment: bootstrap modal uses browser's scrollbar. It works fine for me.

Comment: in the browser, it shows the scroll bar but it won't move. I will do more test and update you guys on how it goes.

Comment: I replaced Bootstrap v3.2 with v2 and it works fine. Maybe its Bootstrap v3.2?

Comment: Update: Adding a max-height and overflow-y: auto to the .modal-body will solve the problem by making it not go over the browser window + a scroll bar within the modal (not the browser).

Any better way to solve this?